# Graph drawing and updating in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

My target browser is the latest version of Chrome (only!) so I want to use the latest technology to get the best performance/visuals etc...

I will be getting the initial (directed) graph and subsequent updates as JSON over a websocket and I want to be able to update the graph as I receive updates.

I've used D3 in the past but as I understand, that is Javascript/SVG, it seems a bit silly to use Javascript when I only have to target Chrome, so I am wondering if I should be looking at another technology/library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to create Live-updating charts using native chrome's ability and HTML 5, I can highly recommend [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

[The API](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) is quite straightforward:

Create an HTML5 canvas:

```
<canvas id="chartCanvas"></canvas>
```

Let's create a pie chart for wins and losses in a Tic-Tac-Toe game, so initialize the graph:

```
var ctx = $("#chartCanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Pie([
    { value: 1, color: "#F7464A", highlight: "#FF5A5E", label: "X Wins" },
    { value: 1, color: "#5F8BC1", highlight: "#5AD3D1", label: "O Wins" },
    { value: 1, color: "#FDB45C", highlight: "#FFC870", label: "Draws"  }
],{});
```

Now update the value, one of two options, reset whole data set:

```
chart.segments = [
    { value: 2, color: "#F7464A", highlight: "#FF5A5E", label: "X Wins" },
    { value: 1, color: "#5F8BC1", highlight: "#5AD3D1", label: "O Wins" },
    { value: 1, color: "#FDB45C", highlight: "#FFC870", label: "Draws" }
];
```

Or update a single value:

```
chart.segments[0].value = 2; // Updates 'X Wins'
```

Finally, show the updated data-set:

```
chart.update();
```

On a side note, I like updating the data-set on real time, and enforce update frequency either by timing it externally [using `setInterval()` for example], or by throttling.

Sources:

- [Chart.js Website](http://www.chartjs.org/)
- Chart.js Documentation: [Getting started](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)
- Chart.js Documentation: [Creating a Chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart)